# Using Debezium with AWS Documentdb

Tags: debezium, aws-documentdb, debezium-engine

Hi all I am trying to use debezium mongodb connector with aws documentdb. Since document db don't have oplog whether debezium will work with Aws document db change streams?

Answer (score 0):

Debezium supports [change streams](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/mongodb.html#_change_stream_mode) capture mode, it should work fine with Amazon DocumentDB.